# how to get and install Intel i915 drivers on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics, i915

Good day all

please could someone help me as i think I am a bit stuck, I want to install the Intel 915 drivers on my HP Elitebook 2540p (yes i know its an artifact), I am using this laptop as a side project to learn and understand Linux and its interfaces a bit better, so my question to you is how and where do I go / get the drivers to install on Kubuntu 18.04

Comment: Welcome on AskUbuntu! Can you please tell us at which point you get stuck, an exact issue? Did you check which driver is installed? You can check with `sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'`

Comment: i have checked i have the intel i915 driver

Comment: If you have installed already then please specify the issue.

Comment: okay so I am trying to install a windows game on my Linux system but I keep on getting a error saying "the program Launcher.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close" but I have installed every single application and ran every script to install the game, so my train of thought is that the GPU drivers are out of date or not installed so now I am asking how can I install the drivers to see if that is the solution to my problem

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu has Intel video drivers by default in the package xserver-xorg-video-intel. But you can install the newest version from ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```